# Convex hull algorithm in $O(\min(mn, n\log n))$

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I am looking for an algorithm to compute the convex hull of a set of $n$ points $P$. The hull should contains $m$ points. This algorithm should work in time $O(\min(mn,n \log n))$.

My first guess was QuickHull, which has a best case running time of $O(n \log n ) $ and a worst case running time time of $O(n^2)$. However, I am a little bit confused about the fact that this convex hull does not have to contain all points. Can I ignore this? I guess yes because I must assume the worst case and this would include all points.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Have you seen other Convex Hull algorithms than Quick Hull? When $m = n$ (for example your points are on circle), you cannot ignore it, and your $m * n$ is just $n^2$ so it looks like Quick Hull description. "Chan and Liu" convex hull might interest you. Are you looking for $\Theta(n~log~m)$?

Comment: Yes I have seen quite a few other algorithms....I am not looking for Θ(n log m), I am looking for something which has either O(mn) or O(n log n) runtime.

Comment: What does the phrase "the convex hull of a set of $n$ points $P$ which contains $m$ points" mean?

Comment: Sorry I'll rewrite this. There are $n$ possible points and the convex hull should contain $m$ of that.

Comment: You cannot ignore the difference between $n^2$ and $nm$. It's like ignoring the difference between $O(V+E)$ and $O(V^2)$ in graph algorithms.

Comment: Have you checked Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms

Comment: Can I say: Okay, I have one algorithm A with runtime $O(mn)$ and an algorithm B with runtime $O(n log n)$. I'll let A run until $m > log n$. If he didn't find an result until then, I'll let B run. The overall runtime will then be $O(log n + n log n) = O(2 n log n) = O(n log n)$, or, if the result is found before $O(nm)$.

Comment: I cannot see anything helpful on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to run two algorithms in parallel, one which runs in time $O(mn)$, and one which runs in time $O(n\log n)$. When one of the algorithms outputs a solution, you stop the other one. This runs in time $O(\min(mn,n\log n))$.

In fact, you can do better – [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms) lists several $O(n\log m)$ algorithms, which is strictly better than the guarantee you are looking for.

Comment: Do I have to run the algorithms in parallel or is it ok if I do it sequential?
So you think all $O(n log m)$ algorithms are suited for this task?

Comment: I believe you can answer both questions yourself. Try to use the definitions of running time and big O.

Comment: 1) I guess I answered this in the comments above. It is possible. 2) $O(min(mn, nlog n) \Rightarrow f < c * min(mn, nlogn)$..and now?

Comment: The point is that an $O(n\log m)$ algorithm is also an $O(\min(mn,n\log n))$ algorithm, a fact I'll let you prove yourself. (Similarly, an $O(n)$ algorithm is also an $O(n^2)$ algorithm.)

Comment: Okay...I guess I could do a case differentiation in the proof. Case 1: $mn>n \text{ log } n$ and $n \text{ log } m <= n \text{ log } n$ which is obviously true. Case 2: $mn < n \text{ log } n$ and $n \text{ log } m$ must be $< mn$ which is also true.

Comment: In fact you don't need any case analysis. Since $\log m = O(m)$ we get $n\log m = O(nm)$, and since $m \leq n$ we get $n\log m \leq n\log n$.